# Python: Solving math in string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using regex to solve basic math in strings, like `'1+(-5)^2'`. I want to use regex to find the number before ^ (base, in this case (-5)) and the number after ^ (exponent, in this case 2) and then replace (-5)^2 with base ** exponent (25 in this case). The numbers are real, I used integers in the example to make it more clear.

The string can be any mathematical expression, and the exponential part can be in any of these forms:

```
>>> (-5)^(-2)
('(-5)', '(-2)')
>>> (-5)^2
('(-5)', '2')
>>> 5^(-2)
('5', '(-2)')
>>> 5^2
('5', '2')
>>> -5^2
('5', '2')
```

Even forms where the brackets are redundant, like:

```
>>> (5)^(+2) 
('(5)', '(+2)')
```

I tried this:

```
import re

a = '1+(-5)^2'

while True:
    exp = re.search('((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\^((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))', a)
    exp_list = list(exp.groups())
    base = exp_list[0].replace('(', '')
    base = base.replace(')', '')
    exponent = exp_list[1].replace('(', '')
    exponent = exponent.replace(')', '')
    if exp:
        temp = (float(base)) ** float(exponent)
        a = re.sub('(\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\^(\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', str(temp), a, count=1)
        print a
    if not exp:
        break
```

I have two problems:

1. It never breaks out of the loop (I need the loop because there can be ^ more than once in the string)
2. It does not replace temp in the string a.

Comment: Is this part of a course as there have been a lot of similar questions lately?

Comment: You can't use a regex for that. You'll need to write a parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons 'eval' function to evaluate these e.g.

```
expr = '3*5'
print eval(eval)  # returns 15
```

Comment: I don't want to use eval, because the user inputs the string and also the strings can be rather complicated, with brackets and variables.

Comment: You can pass whatever input the user gives you directly to eval (or ast.literal_eval fo safety) and they can be as complicated expressions as you like, it will still be able to evaluate them...unless the point of your exercise is to learn regex I really would recommend this

Comment: I missed your comment about variables - if you need to do symbolic calculation then you'll need something more complicated like sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples

Comment: @JMzance,`literal_eval` is not going to evaluate an expression, eval should also never be used taking input from users

Comment: eval works fine so long as you check the sanitise the input.

Comment: @JMzance,  *You can pass whatever input the user gives you directly to eval (or ast.literal_eval fo safety) and they can be as complicated expressions as you like, it will still be able to evaluate them.*,no you can't.

Comment: 'eval' will evaluate numerical expressions in string form.  You can, first, check to see if the user of the code is doing something dodgy like importing extra libraries or trying to execute commands on the file system and, if so, you can refuse.  But for evaluating numerical expressions - it's fine.

Comment: @JMzance,  `ast.literal_eval`  **does and will not evaluate expressions**, the OP as asked for a regex solution not how to evaluate  a user string

Answer (score 0):

> I have two problems:
>
> 1. It never breaks out of the loop (I need the loop because there can be ^ more than once in the string)
> 2. It does not replace temp in the string a.

This is actually one and the same problem - since it loops until there is nothing more to replace, and it fails to replace what is there, it loops forever.

That it fails to replace what it should, comes from a small but crucial difference in the patterns you use in `re.search()` and `re.sub()` (blanks inserted for easier comparison):

`((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\^((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))`
                         `↕`                                                                
`(   \([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+) \)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \^(   \([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

You omitted a quantifier `?` in the latter pattern.

The moral of the story is to not use separate patterns when the same thing must be matched and replaced. Change:

```
pattern = \
'((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\^((?:\([\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))'
while True:
    exp = re.search(pattern, a)
    if not exp: break
    …
        a = re.sub(pattern, str(temp), a, 1)
```

---

That all said, of course hek2mgl is right noting: *You can't use a regex for that. You'll need to write a parser for that.*